# Can't find symbol for printer

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class Events{



   File output = new File ("chinese.txt");


  static ArrayList <Event> events = new ArrayList <Event>();


  public static void main(String[]args){


      try{
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("events.txt"));
         File output = new File("chinese.txt");
         PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
         while(sc.hasNext()){        
               //String temp = sc.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(temp);

            int num = sc.nextInt();
            String desc = sc.nextLine();


            events.add(new Event(num,desc));


         }

         //break;   






      }
      catch(Exception e){

         System.out.println("Invalid file");


      }

      Collections.sort(events);

      for(int i = 0; i<events.size();i++){

         System.out.println(events.get(i));
         printer.println(events.get(i).toString()); 
      } 

 `}

}'
```

I create a printer object and a new file object to print the contents of an arraylist but inside my for loop it can't find the symbol and I have tried everything to fix it with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare printer before the try block, otherwise the scope of printer is limited to the try block. This will fix it:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

  PrintWriter printer = null;
  try{
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("events.txt"));
     File output = new File("chinese.txt");
     printer = new PrintWriter(output);
     while(sc.hasNext()){        
           //String temp = sc.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(temp);

        int num = sc.nextInt();
        String desc = sc.nextLine();


        events.add(new Event(num,desc));


     }

     //break;   






  }
  catch(Exception e){

     System.out.println("Invalid file");


  }

  Collections.sort(events);

  for(int i = 0; i<events.size();i++){

     System.out.println(events.get(i));
     printer.println(events.get(i).toString()); 
  }
```

}

Comment: I get a filenotfound error , it wants me to put it in the try block 
                                                                                          
Events.java:12: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
         PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
                               ^

Comment: Thank you sheunis , it works but if I may ask you another question it doesn't write to my file so I change "chinese.txt" to "dog.txt" but its not writing to my file

Answer (score 0):

`printer` is declared inside the try block but you are trying to use it outside it. Include the for loop within the try block and it should solve your problem

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
public class Events{



   File output = new File ("chinese.txt");


  static ArrayList <Event> events = new ArrayList <Event>();


  public static void main(String[]args){


      try{
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("events.txt"));
         File output = new File("chinese.txt");
         PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);
         while(sc.hasNext()){        
               //String temp = sc.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(temp);

            int num = sc.nextInt();
            String desc = sc.nextLine();


            events.add(new Event(num,desc));


         }

         //break;   

          Collections.sort(events);

      for(int i = 0; i<events.size();i++){

         System.out.println(events.get(i));
         printer.println(events.get(i).toString()); 
      } 




      }
      catch(Exception e){

         System.out.println("Invalid file");


      }



 }

}
```

Comment: it does but the reason why I was trying to find another method is it repeatedly prints the data i'm writing and I only want it printed once

Comment: It should print it once as you are not writing it in a loop.

Comment: If your are seeing your original file in your code, you wont see the data there, see the file in the target folder and you will see it getting updated, since JAVA modifies its own copy of file and not the original one

Comment: It still doesn't write anything to the file

Comment: Should I delete the file and try again , I don't have any other ideas

Comment: Could you try to open the file and read the data from it, in your java code after writing it and see if you get the result

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response , no it still is'nt writing to it